# Превышено время ожидания подключение к TCP серверу

Tags: c#, сервер, tcp, digitalocean

Загрузил сервер на DigitalOcean. Запустил его, по новому айпи адресу, который выдал мне хост. Прослушка TCP по ему адресу идет... Пытаюсь подключиться с своего клиента, появляется исключение: Connection timed out. Если кто-то встречал подобную проблему, как вы ее решили?

Comment: _Прослушка TCP по ему адресу идет_ - непонятно что означает. Какой порт открыт на сервере и к какому порту вы обращаетесь? По какому адресу слушает сервер, 0.0.0.0:порт, или 127.0.01:порт, если последнее, то невозможно к такой прослушке подключиться ниоткуда кроме как с локалхоста.

Comment: 207.154.232.128:27018 Я через netcat посмотрел и узнал что этот порт закрыт. А порты 22,25,80,3306 открыты но они уже используются кем-то

Comment: 22 SSH, 25 SMTP, 80 HTTP, 3306 SQL

Comment: Может есть возможность открыть свой порт для прослушивания?

Comment: Так вы открыли 27018, почему он недоступен - без понятия, обратитесь к хостинг-провайдеру с этим вопросом. Если я что-то открываю у себя на сервере, оно сразу же видно снаружи. Вообще, порт 3306 не должен быть открыт наружу ни при каких обстоятельствах, это делает БД уязвимой для атак извне. Этот порт используется только для внутренних коммуникаций сервера.

Comment: В том-то и особенность, что я порт 27018 не открывал. У меня 0 опыта работы с linux и я не знаю как открыть этот порт) Какие команды для этого нужны. Было бы еще замечательно, если бы вы еще написали как скрыть порт 3306

Comment: @aepot я пишу команду: netstat -na | grep :27018 чтобы открыть порт. После чего пишу netcat -z -n -v 207.154.232.128 27018 и пишет что порт не работает

Comment: Порт открывает запущеное серверное приложение, когда начинает его слушать. Дополнительно порт может быть защищен фаерволом. Какая у вас ОС и какой именно фаервол и есть ли он вообще - известно только вам. Судя по тому что вы пишете, кажется вы вообще ошиблись IP адресом. Вам не здесь вопросы задавать надо, а хотя-бы почитать, что такое TCP, порты, как они слушаются и т.д. для начала, это займёт немного времени и снимет массу тупиковых вопросов.

Comment: `netstat` не открывает и не закрывает порты, он всего-лишь показывает, что уже открыто или закрыто. Точнее оно показывает, что открыто, а всё остальное считается закрытым.